# How to bind double click event to CalendarDayButton in Calendar in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, calendar

I am trying to implement a one-year calendar that displays 365 days in one window and I want to bind double click to each day button so that users can add events to each day.

I find a [blog](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd882520.aspx) about customizing Calendar control. However it mentioned that the click event is disabled and he overrode the OnMouseDoubleClick method but might cause new problem.

Is there an elegant way to bind double click event to CalendarDayButton? I tried to use EventSetter in Style setting, it worked with a method that using parameters (object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e), but it cannot work for command.

Answer (score 0):

```
<Calendar.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="CalendarDayButton">
                    <EventSetter Event="MouseDoubleClick" Handler="Cdb_MouseDoubleClick"/>
                </Style>
</Calendar.Resources>
```

code :

```
    private void Cdb_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Double click");
    }
```

Comment: This can work for me as well. Is that possible to bind with a command?